# Sorting ObservableCollection without assigning new()

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to sort ObservableCollection without assigning new one to source. Right now I have this:

```
private void SortingObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<MyObject> toSort)
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(toSort.OrderBy(x => x.Top).ThenBy(x => x.Left));
}
```

It almost works perfectly, but I need to do it without assignign new one.

Desired effect is exactly what I could do on a list:

```
toSort = toSort.OrderBy(x => x.Top).ThenBy(x => x.Left).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of sorting the ObservableCollection, you might want to use a CollectionViewSource. See [How to: Sort Data in a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-sort-data-in-a-view).

Comment: It seems I cannot upvote comments, so just Thank you both very much!